# Are commas and decimal points in SVG path defs ever localised, e.g. "M1,23.4,56"?

Tags: svg, localization

I have some JavaScript in-browser code that reads, parses and writes SVG path definitions on each browser animation frame to create a smooth animation between path definitions. It assumes that when it reads a `d` attribute from an SVG `path` node, the numbers will be separated with spaces or commas, like:

- `M 1.23 4.56`
- `M1.23 4.56`
- `M 1.23,4.56`
- `M1.23,4.56`

Some locales format numbers using commas as the decimal point, like `1,23` meaning *"one point two three"*. Is there any combination of locales and browsers where an SVG path `d` attribute meaning *Move to x co-ordinate one point two three and y co-ordinate four point five six* might be returned like:

- `M 1,23 4,56`
- `M1,23.4,56`

In other words, can I be certain that if an SVG path definition contains `,` it is being used as a number separator?

I've looked in the SVG spec and couldn't find anything about locales in this context, and my attempts to test it have always given commas as seperators only, but I'm not sure if that could be because my locale-spoofing isn't being registered properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No per the [SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#BasicDataTypes) a number is either

> number ::= integer
>              | [+-]? [0-9]* "." [0-9]+

or

> number ::= integer ([Ee] integer)?
>              | [+-]? [0-9]* "." [0-9]+ ([Ee] integer)?

Paths have their own [BNF](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataBNF) but it's basically the same number definition, . is always a decimal point.

Comment: Great, thanks. Reading that BNF definition made me notice two possible other cases relevant to my code: unless I've misread the spec, `M 12-34` is valid and would be parsed like `M 12 -34`, and `M 1.2.3` is valid and would be parsed like `M 1.2 0.3`

Comment: Indeed, spaces can sometimes be omitted altogether, basically parse as much as you can and the moment that would make the existing token invalid treat that as a new token.